# Akka flow Input (`In`) as Output (`Out`)

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I am trying to write a piece of code which does following:-

1. Reads a large csv file from remote source like s3.
2. Process the file record by record.
3. Send notification to user
4. Write the output to a remote location

Sample record in input csv:

```
recordId,name,salary
1,Aiden,20000
2,Tom,18000
3,Jack,25000
```

My input case class which represents a record in input csv:

`case class InputRecord(recordId: String, name: String, salary: Long)`

Sample record in output csv (that needs to be written):

```
recordId,name,designation
1,Aiden,Programmer
2,Tom,Web Developer
3,Jack,Manager
```

My output case class which represents a record in input csv:

`case class OutputRecord(recordId: String, name: String, designation: String)`

Reading a record using akka stream csv (uses Alpakka reactive s3 https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/s3.html):

```
def readAsCSV: Future[Source[Map[String, ByteString], NotUsed]] = 
S3.download(s3Object.bucket, s3Object.path)
      .runWith(Sink.head)
// This is then converted to csv
```

Now I have a function to process the records:

```
def process(input: InputRecord): OutputRecord =
//if salary > avg(salary) then Manager
//else Programmer
```

Function to write the OutputRecord as csv

```
def writeOutput:Sink[ByteString, Future[MultipartUploadResult]] = 
S3.multipartUpload(s3Object.bucket,
                       s3Object.path,
                       metaHeaders = MetaHeaders(Map())
```

Function to send email notification:

```
def notify : Flow[OutputRecord, PushResult, NotUsed]
//if notification is sent successfully PushResult has some additional info
```

Stitching it all together

```
readAsCSV.flatMap { recordSource =>
  recordSource.map { record
    val outputRecord = process(record)
    outputRecord
  }
  .via(notify) //Error: Line 15
  .to(writeOutput) //Error: Line 16
  .run()
}
```

**On Line 15 & 16 I am getting an error, I am either able to add Line 15 or Line 16 but not both since both `notify` & `writeOutput` needs `outputRecord`. Once notify is called I loose my `outputRecord`.**

**Is there a way I can add both `notify` and `writeOutput` to same graph?**

I am not looking for parallel execution as I want to first call `notify` and then only `writeOutput`. So this is not helpful: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-parallelism.html#parallel-processing

The use case seems very simple to me but some how I am not able to find a clean solution.

Comment: The type a `Flow` outputs must be the type the next`Flow` takes as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of [`notify`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) is a `PushResult`, but the input of `writeOutput` is `ByteString`. Once you change that it will compile. In case you need `ByteString`, get the same from `OutputRecord`.

BTW, in the sample code that you have provided, a similar error exists in `readCSV` and `process`.